# not italic just one word in labels ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I think, I have problem with one graph and need your help. Because I am confused a little bit.
We have been preparing a manuscript and I plotted the graph. However, the referee asked me do that the "spp" is not italic in labels. All of them should be italic except just "spp." in *Blennius* spp.

```
df_mak_2 <- read_csv("df_mak_2.csv")

ggplot(df_mak_2, aes( x= x, y=Freq, ,fill=z))+
  geom_col(width = 0.9,position = "stack")+
facet_wrap(~s)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 1))+
  xlab("Season")+
  ylab("Count")+
  labs(fill="Species")+
  theme_bw(base_size=12, base_family="Times New Roman")+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0.3,"lines"), 
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.text  = element_text(face = "italic"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

[image: this_graph]

Comment: I could not find to load csv file... sorry

Comment: It would probably be easiest to use ggtext (https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext) and format all as italic except the "spp.". I think the author gave a nice talk (with micro-organism examples) in https://rstudio.com/resources/rstudioconf-2020/spruce-up-your-ggplot2-visualizations-with-formatted-text/.

Comment: you can use the labels parameter in `scale_fill_discrete`

Comment: @teunbrand thank you very much. I have opened it. It is usefull package for me..

Comment: yes thanks for the intro to ggtext @teunbrand

Comment: I think ggtext has not been ready for R 4.0.0.  "Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘ggtext’ is not available (for R version 4.0.0 Patched)"

Comment: @pomatomus ; you have to install from github: `remotes::install_github("wilkelab/ggtext")`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `labels` argument of `scale_fill_discrete`

```
library(ggplot2)

# Some data
data(mtcars)
mtcars$gear = factor(mtcars$gear, labels=c("w2", "word spp", "word2 spp"))

# change the relevant label to "italic non-italic"
lbs = brk = levels(mtcars$gear)
lbs[match("word spp", brk)] = expression(italic("word")~spp)
lbs[match("word2 spp", brk)] = expression(italic("word2")~spp)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(am), mpg, fill=gear)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
   scale_fill_discrete(breaks=brk, labels=lbs) +
   theme(legend.text  = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

[image]

Comment: you're welcome. You may also want to add `legend.text.align = 0` to your `theme`

Comment: what do you suggest, if there are two or three spp.. when I have tried for multiple labels I got the message like "comparison is not allowed for expressions"

Comment: 2ng go ... better to index using integers, so try `lbs[match("word spp", brk)] = expression(italic("word")~spp)`

Answer (score 1):

after the valuable comments of @user20650 , here  the codes are to help the others...

```
lbs = brk = levels(df_mak_2$z)        
lbs[lbs == "Blennius spp."] = expression(italic("Blennius")~spp.)
    lbs[match("Parablennius spp.",brk)] = expression(italic("Parablennius")~spp.)


    ggplot(df_mak_2, aes( x= x, y=Freq, ,fill=z))+
      geom_col(width = 0.9,position = "stack")+
    facet_wrap(~s)+
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 1))+
      xlab("Season")+
      ylab("Count")+
      labs(fill="Species")+
      theme_bw(base_size=12, base_family="Times New Roman")+
      theme(panel.spacing = unit(0.3,"lines"), 
            legend.position = "right",
            legend.text  = element_text(face = "italic"),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
            legend.text.align = 0)+
      scale_fill_discrete(breaks=brk, labels=lbs)
```